Photointerrupter with internal pull up Circuit design
I'm using this photointerrupter as a switch RPI-0451E The forward current IF = is about 10-11ma and Im using the PIC18F internal weak pullup. The datasheet states it can output between 50 microamps to 400 microamps. When I measured the current on some devices are about typical 250 microamps. However, so far I seen on a few units not all after some time months, the output goes up to around 2v to 3v oppose to our saturation vce of 0.4v.Not sure why? When messing the current I still see 250microamps and the 10ma-11ma on the led. I did some tests at diffrent foward currents and took off the output from the pic and place a trimpot up to 1.7M. These are the results I see
At IF= 10-11ma with very low IC
Ic = current can be as low 15v/1.7M but goes from 0.6 to 4.36v and still good time reponse
Ic= 5v/1.3M, 0.6v to 4.60v
with this IF can be much lower than the 10ma.
Now I tried to simulate the range of the pic weak pull currents
At IC =  5v/100k = 0.050ma at IF= 10ma-11ma  is normal 0.4 to 4.88v
At "typical" IC =  5v/20k = 0.250ma at IF =10ma-11ma still okay 0.4 to 4.88v, but simualting the led light ouput deacy lowering the IF to 6.5ma we reach Vce to low 1v.
At IC =  5v/12k about 0.400ma  at IF =10ma- 11ma still okay 0.4 to 4.88v but at this max if the IC increases to 0.500ma then we reach Vce = 1V but is not possible since it goes only up to 0.400, but lowering the IF current to about 8-9ma then will start seesing the vce to beagin rasing to 1v.
This data shows like I have a bad desgin, I like to use the weak pullup and it looks like I need to place an extra resitor in series (I could use a unpopluated resitor in the board) but not sure what value to place 10k or something larger like 50k or 100k, of course this will bring the pic weak pull current 50 microamp to 400 microamp  to lower output currents, or is there a way to keep using the weak pull up? Or increase the IF curent led to let say 15m based on the transfer output graph, but not sure how much decaying of the led will be compare to 10ma. I attched some images of the datasheets. Thank you.





I suggest you turn off the pullup and depend entirely on an external 1% resistor.
With all the variations associated with optocouplers (LED aging, dirt in the gap, temperature changes), who needs an extra 4:1 variation to deal with?
Also, you probably know this, but the speed is highly dependent on the load resistor. They offer misleading data by showing a 100Ω load, which few can use. If you have a 50kΩ load the switching times will be ~500x slower.

yes I could get rid of the external resitor, it looks this will be the best option. and will be both a program and pcb modification. Not  just a pcb modfication . Not worried about time as long is not more than 1 sec. what will be a good RL 50k? Also you know what they mean on IC min 0.160 and typ 0.45, do they mean at IF =10ma , the max Ic allow sometimes will be .160 or they mean it starts at this value?

The 0.16mA is measured with 5V across the transistor, with 10mA flowing through the LED and at 25°C. You need it at a logic '0' including some noise margin and over the life of the unit, maybe allowing for some dirt and aged LED. It's characterized at 100uA which would be 50kΩ for a 5V supply and that's guaranteed to work out of the box, but you might want to go with 100kΩ to allow more margin.

I otherwise agree with this answer and would also suggest an external resistor, as the manufacturing tolerances of MCU pull-ups are rather large, and they typically are not even real resistors but current sources. I only disagree with the resistor needing to be 1%, the tolerances of the circuit are already much larger and for a simple pull-up resistor such precision is not necessary, as in the end the circuit has to work with 5% supply tolerance and other environmental tolerances such as changes caused by temperature, so using 1% resistor compared to e.g. 5% might not offer any advantage.

@Justme Yes, I agree it offers no real advantage in this case, but they're the same price these days, close enough. Unless you're building hundreds of thousands, everyone should be using 1% resistors. One less part to stock for when it does matter.

Thank you, guys I'm leaning toward the RL 50K and keeping the 10ma forward current. giving me 100uA . I already have a 50k resistor on the board that is not used that I can reroute to be used as pull-up without the need to change the Bom materials. or stencil pcb . Unless 100k is needed. it looks like at 50k even if the LED runs at 5ma is might keep the saturation vce but not sure if is the same as led degrading overtime.  will this 50k will allow me with good margin at 10ma?

I like to see about 3:1 typical margin (IOW, it will work at ~3.5mA if you build one or two of them). You're using Rohm which probably has a better quality IR LED than some.. if the consequences of failure are minor and it's easier then ..

yes a 100k will definitely give me a better margin. I was hoping to use the 50k which it looks it might still work at 5ma.

Resistance of the internal pull-up on these PIC micros isn't well defined, since it isn't technically a resistor, rather it's implemented by some kind of  transistor arrangement exhibiting what looks like a resistance. The CTR of this opto-interruptor is very low, 4% or so, and you're forced to operate with \$I_C<400\mu A\$. If I understood you correctly, that figure seems to diminish over time, perhaps due to debris building up over the photo-transistor window, or perhaps due to LED/transistor aging or temperature dependence.
Whatever the reason, with \$I_F=10mA\$ it would be safer to operate in the close vicinity of \$I_C=200\mu A\$, and I don't think you'll get any guarantees from the PIC micro that its internal pull-up will produce those exact conditions. Consequently, my opinion is that it is not wise to rely on that pull-up, especially if speed is an issue.
You would be better served using your own pull-up resistance, deliberately chosen to pass 200μA:
$$ R = \frac{5V-0.4V}{200\mu A} \approx 22k\Omega $$
If you saturate that transistor, it can take a while for it to recover, introducing delays of many microseconds before the collector even begins to rise again in potential. Using a 22kΩ resistor, to produce \$I_C=200\mu A\$ will certainly saturate it, but not by much; you'll need to observe the collector to see if recovery is quick enough in your particular application.
Regarding transition times of the photo-transistor's collector potential, they will depend greatly upon the pull-up resistance. The lower that resistance, the faster the rise time. Sadly, you're kind of stuck with 22kΩ, or maybe a little lower. You can improve rise time by replacing that resistance with a current source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
$$ I = \frac{0.6V}{R_1} $$
This arrangement has very high transconductance, significantly more than the photo-transistor & resistor pair alone, producing more abrupt output transitions as \$I_C\$ rises and falls through 220μA. You are also operating the photo-transistor under very tightly controlled conditions, which are largely independent of variations of device parameters over time and temperature. The cost is complexity, and another couple of transistors, but the benefits in performance may be worth it.

The few ones I have seen with vce high as more than 2v the IF was still 10ma and the IC current don't he pull up was about 230uA. which is below the max 400UA. Most likely like you said this maybe was due debris building up over the photo-transistor window, or perhaps something else. For other comments, it looks like a RL of 50K will be okay to use, give me an IC of about 100uA. I'm not worried about time as long is not more than 1sec.
